# C# type argument constraints

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm trying to do something a certain way... but I'm certain there's a better way

```
public interface IMix
{
    T Mix<T>(List<T> values) where T : IMix;
}
```

The problem with this is that if I want to "Mix" 5 values, then I need to do `value1.Mix(others)` but that is not clean. Plus, the type of T needs to be the same type as whatever class implements the interface. So, this doesn't really work.

I was thinking something like this:

```
public static class MixWrapper
{
    public static T Mix<T>(List<T> values);
}
```

But that obviously won't work because I have to define the body in `MixWrapper`

EDIT: to clear up some misunderstanding, these are not real math averages, I could just as easily say "Fuse" or anything else. For example I could be trying to "average" a list some struct or other class.

EDIT 2:
One example could be a class like this

```
class Sequence : IMix
{
    List<int> sequence;
    double period;
    double weight;
}
```

The "Mix" in this case would need to return a `Sequence` that was built this way: the resulting period is the weighted average of the periods based on the weight. The weight is the sum of the weights, and the sequence is the weighted average of the sequences after they have been timescaled down to the resulting period. Suffice to say, any complicated method that you could think of needs to be accounted for

Comment: Your second method is essentially how the `Enumerable<T>` class does it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx. Why not do it that way? For that matter, why not just call the `Average` extension method? Or is there something you're not telling us, like you need a method to extract the values that will be averaged?

Comment: I think what you are really asking is "how do I constrain it to types that support the + and / operators?"  Since you'll need those operators to compute an average.  That's not possible, a fairly infamous restriction of .NET generics.

Comment: @Jay after your edit it's not clear what are you trying to achieve. Can you show some example of Average/Fuse/Mix?

Comment: will do, but someone answered the question... Still, for completeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the type `T` on your interface and just fill it with the same type as the class when you're implementing it:

```cs
public interface IMix<T>
{
    T Mix(List<T> values);
}

public class ConcreteObjects : IMix<ConcreteObjects>
{
    public ConcreteObjects Mix(List<ConcreteObjects> values)
    {
        // do mixing
    }
}
```

This also leaves the door open for other classes to be able to mix ConcreteObjects if need be.

Comment: So simple... I don't know why I didn't think of that. Now I just wish there could be static methods in an interface.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to calculate average of some list, then you can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx):

```
var value = list.Average(x => x.SomeProperty);
```

Comment: But I don't want to average just the one property, I want to "mix" a bunch of properties together

Comment: @Jay you can use selector, which will calculate average on several properties. E.g. `list.Average(x => x.SomeProperty + x.OtherProperty)`. Selector is just a delegate of `Func<TSource, TResult>` type, which accepts variable from your sequence and returns some value, which will be used for calculating average.

Comment: nope, it's not a true average. it's closer to a standard deviation. See my updated question

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for an `extension method`.

You need to define a static method somewhere (some helper class, I suppose) like this:

```
public static T Average<T>(this List<T> list) where T : IAverage
{
    return // average stuff
}
```

Now you just need to include your helper class with `using` and you can do something like this:
`AverageClass` implements `IAverage`

```
List<IAverage> list = new List<AverageClass>();
var average = list.Average();
```